# Grub rescue screen on dual boot laptop

Tags: windows, grub, linux-mint, bootloader

I have a laptop with a dual boot of Linux Mint 17 and Windows 7. This evening I booted Mint and unconsciously pressed some buttons and came into a HP backup screen. I exited this screen and now my laptop won't start.

I know I have made some moves to make it possible to suspend the laptop, and it was suspended when I started it.

Now when I boot I get this message:

> error: no such partition
> Entering rescue mode...
>  grub rescue>

When I boot from Linux mint CD and run sudo fdisk -l and try to mount sda5 I get the following output:

[image]

I have no idea how to fix Grub and Windows boot loader. I have no CD with Windows.

I hope someone can help me out and explain what is wrong and how I an fix it. I can provide all information requested.

Comment: Do you see the grub menu at boot?  If so, can you hit `e` on the entry it boots by default, and see if it has a `resume=` line?

Comment: I have no boot menu. Only grubrescue screen. The problem is similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/424257/how-to-solve-a-error-grub-rescue-no-such-partition-error.